# Bash script not behaving like I'd expect

Tags: bash

I've poured over question after question searching here and on Google, but something in my syntax is messed up. Any assistance is appreciated.

Basically I've got another function that sets the load and threshold, as well as $FORCE variable. The script needs to do the "stuff" if it meets either the first or the second condition. The variables have been set correctly, which I've confirmed via `echo` in the script while debugging.

```
if ([ $LOAD -ge "$THRESH" ] || [ $FORCE=1 ]);
then
    # do some other stuff
fi
```

From what I can see, my spacing of the brackets around the conditions are correct. They no longer produce `bash [: missing`]'` errors like they were.

The script runs fine, except for one issue...it runs no matter what. It's like it's completely ignoring the `[ $FORCE=1 ]` part, even though I can see that `$FORCE` is in fact actually 0.

Should I be using single quotes or some other method?

Comment: Also, I've tried `[ $FORCE="1" ]` (with quotes), but that didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Putting parentheses doesn't help you, it just forces the tests to run in a subshell: `if [[ $LOAD -eq $THRESH ]] || [[ $FORCE = 1 ]]` is sufficient

Comment: Love it. It's cleaner now, and works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting spaces around `=`:

```
if ([ $LOAD -ge "$THRESH" ] || [ $FORCE = 1 ]);
then
    # do some other stuff
fi
```

Comment: Ah dang it...that was totally it. You saved the day!! Thank you.

Comment: @WillAshworth the test commands work differently based on how many arguments they're given. With a single argument, the test is "is this string empty" and for "0=1", the string is not empty, therefore a success exit status.